# JavaScript render SVG from text

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an svg element as **plain text**

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

How can I render this on a HTML page by inserting it with JavaScript/jquery without recreating every node with

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")
```

(because otherwise it will not be rendered)

Answer (score 2):

try the following code.

```
var svg = '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 30 30" enable-background="new 0 0 30 30" xml:space="preserve">'+    
    '<path fill="#156BB1" d="M22.906,10.438c0,4.367-6.281,14.312-7.906,17.031c-1.719-2.75-7.906-12.665-7.906-17.031S10.634,2.531,15,2.531S22.906,6.071,22.906,10.438z"/>'+
    '<circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="15" cy="10.677" r="3.291"/></svg>';

    var mysvg = new Image();
    mysvg.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + escape(svg);
```

and then use `mysvg`variable to place it where ever you want within your html.

Answer (score 2):

Use innerHTML to insert it.

```js
document.documentElement.innerHTML = '<svg height="100" width="100">\n    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />\n</svg>'
```

Answer (score 1):

do this with JQuery:

```
var str = '<svg height="100" width="100">  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg>'

$("body").append(str)
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/8L7esgrm/)